# How to find a node of an XML and remove it

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an xml like this

```
<Order>
 <OrderSections>
      <OrderSection type="1" name="S 1" id="3">
         <ShippingAmount>15.02</ShippingAmount>
      </OrderSection>
      <OrderSection type="1" name="S 2" id="4">
         <ShippingAmount>0</ShippingAmount>
      </OrderSection>
 </OrderSections>
</Order>
```

How can I find the order section with id=4 and remove it from the XmlDocument ?, I was looking at [this example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0e00125b-1198-482f-9b65-9bbfa167f995/), but that is different because the value being searched belongs to a node like

```
<players>
<player> 
    <name>User2</name>
 </player>
</players>
```

but my XML has the id within the `<OrderSection>` attribute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@` for attributes:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Order/OrderSections/OrderSection[@id='4']");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Take a look at the [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Use the XmlDocument class and xpath to find the elements

```
string path = "orders.xml";
XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
XMLDoc.Load(path);
foreach (XmlNode entry in XMLDoc.SelectNodes("//OrderSection[@id='4']"))
{
    entry.ParentNode.RemoveChild(entry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Xml:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
xdoc.Descendants("OrderSection")
    .Where(os => (int)os.Attribute("id") == 3)
    .Remove();
xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```